# Conditionally Redirecting Users depending on props status

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a Dashboard component and I'm trying to conditionally redirect users depending on whether they have an account created or not. If they currently don't have an account they need to be redirected to my CreateAccount component. If they already have an account, I want to redirect them to my SelectAccount component.

With the below code my users that already have an account keep getting redirected to my  Create an Account component. I have a feeling that this code is returning true because it's running the checks before the props are populated but not sure how to fix it.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.accounts !== this.props.accounts && (!this.props.activeAccount && this.props.accounts)) {
        if (!_.isEmpty(this.props.accounts)) {
          history.push('/accounts/selectAccount');
        }
      }

      if (prevProps.accounts !== this.props.accounts && (_.isEmpty(this.props.accounts) === true)) {
        if (_.isEmpty(this.props.accounts)) {
          history.push('/accounts/createAccount');
        }
      }
    }
```

Edit: To troubleshoot the issue I added the following code:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.accounts !== prevProps.accounts && _.size(this.props.accounts) >= 1) {
      console.log("I see some accounts")
    }
    if (this.props.accounts !== prevProps.accounts && _.isEmpty(this.props.accounts)) {
      console.log("There are no accounts")
    }
```

what's happening is that for a user that already has an account, on the first iteration of render it's saying "There are no accounts" followed by a "I see some accounts". Is there any way to make this logic work after my api call?

Comment: `console.log(prevProps);`

Comment: @MattOestreich so it seems like the problem is that there's two renderinigs going on. on the first render the object is empty and on the second it has items in it. 
the problem in my code is my conditions are being executed on the first render, when everything is empty